# Single Flow Interview Sending Duplicate Email Alert

Tags: email-alert, screen-flow

I have a screen flow on a custom Lightning Page that checks the status of a process and displays the next step. Importantly, it runs automatically when the screen is loaded (with no 'start' screen), and runs through the criteria to decide which 'step' screen to land in. Emails go out for each step.

In the section of the flow below, the center email alert usually gets sent twice. The flow is only running once, as the log shows. Then there are two basically identical log files - one for each email send. They each reference the same Flow interview ID.

Here's the question: The email goes out twice only when I click 'Finish' on the 'Invoices Created Screen' (bottom left). The Apex code changes data so that the top left decision follows the 'no' path the next time the flow runs. The email does not go out twice if I simply refresh the page (and thus the flow) instead of clicking 'Finish'.

How is clicking 'Finish', and restarting the flow in that way, changing the number of emails vs restarting the flow with a browser refresh? If I remove that screen, then the page refreshes automatically after the Apex code runs, but I still get two emails. The only way to get a single email is to put the screen at the end, hide the 'Finish' button, and ask the user to refresh the browser manually.

I don't know what to look for in the Flow execution log, but the log is 2.12 MB in both the single email and duplicate email scenarios.

[image: Flow Diagram]
[image: Log List]

Comment: Using the Developer Console in Salesforce (⚙️| Developer Console) might shed more light on this. In general, one execution should be one flow and result in one log file. You might get more logs depending on what else is on the page, but digging through the logs should help here.

Comment: Thanks! I've edited the question with a bunch more info after further troubleshooting. I have a workaround, but now I'm just really curious.